# What is the minimum diameter for vertical bars in a column according to ACI?

Tags: structural-engineering, design, structural-analysis, building-design

What is the minimum for vertical bars in a column according to ACI and I am looking for a particular condition where diameter must be greater than 0.625 in.
(when using S-concrete for column design it gives a warning that diameter must be 0.625 in. but I couldn't find anywhere in the ACI that include this condition)

If any article or in any clause in ACI refer to this condition please share.

Comment: What is ACI? you should define it or it will be difficult to understand your question.

Comment: @MrYouMath, ACI is the [American Concrete Institute](https://www.concrete.org/). It's a pretty standard acronym in structural engineering. I'm a Brazilian and I know of it.

Comment: I'm not an expert on ACI, but codes frequently have limits like "diameter must be greater/smaller than X% of the column's biggest/smallest dimension." What are your column dimensions?

Comment: The Brazilian code, for instance, defines that vertical rebar must be $\phi\geq10\text{ mm} \approx 0.4\text{ in}$ and $\phi\leq w/8$, where $w$ is the column's smallest dimension.

Comment: @Wasabi In my opinion using acronyms without further explanation is not a good practice. I believe that there are many people on ESE who don't or didn't know this acronym including myself.

Comment: @MrYouMath - so for the first use of the acronym you should address the OP...

Comment: Have you checked the S-Concrete manual / support?

Comment: S-Concrete manual only states the following : "Diameter of Vertical Bars does not meet the Minimum Required.
CSA-A23.3 for a robust cage, use d >= 16 mm
ACI 318 for a robust cage, use d >= 0.625 in
BS8110 / CP65 Clause 3.12.5.3 of Part 1
EN-1992-1-1 Clause 9.5.2(1)" it usually states which clause from the ACI but it didn't and I couldn't find any condition about vertical bars diameters in ACI